# refresh datagrid items without losing selected row - XAML

Tags: wpf, xaml, wpfdatagrid

I have two `datagrid'`s ( Master/detaiL). I refresh my window using `DispatcherTimer` for every 5 secs. when I select any row on my Master grid, the focus on the selected row stays only for those 5 secs, after that the selection focus moves to the top most row.

how to overcome this issue in XAML?

**EDIT**

```
 public partial class MyWindow : Window
{
    ProdEntities _prodEntities = new ProdEntities();

    public MyWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Window_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            RebindData();
            SetTimer();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
        }
    }

    private void SetTimer()
    {
        DispatcherTimer dispatcherTimer = new DispatcherTimer();
        dispatcherTimer.Tick += new EventHandler(dispatcherTimer_Tick);
        dispatcherTimer.Interval = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 5);
        dispatcherTimer.Start();
    }

    protected void dispatcherTimer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        RebindData();
    }

    private void RebindData()
    {
        CollectionViewSource serversViewSource = (CollectionViewSource)(FindResource("serversViewSource"));
        IQueryable<Server> serversQuery = this.GetServersQuery(_prodEntities );
        serversViewSource.Source = serversQuery.ToList();

        //serversViewSource.View.Refresh();
    }

    private IQueryable<Server> GetServersQuery(ProdEntities _prodEntities)
    {
        var serversQuery = _prodEntities.Servers.Where(c => c.Components.Any());
        return serversQuery;
    }

    private void SaveChanges_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        _prodEntities.SaveChanges();
    }       
}
```

XAML

```
  <DataGrid AutoGenerateColumns="False" Foreground="DarkBlue"   DataContext="StaticResource serversComponentsViewSource}"
 ItemsSource="{Binding}" Name="componentsDataGrid">
```

Comment: Can you please show the code ? Are you Clearing ItemsSource the Grid everytime?

Comment: Kindly check my edited code. Iam just calling the dispatcherTimer every 5 secs

Comment: Are you doing everything in View? Are you not using MVVM ?

Comment: no, i m not using MVVM atm

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hi you need to preserve SelectedItem of your DataGrid before you call

```
serversViewSource.Source = serversQuery.ToList();
```

and then assign it back to SelectedItem of that DataGrid. But you will have to find the item in Collection that has same Values as that in preserved SelectedItem before you assign that object back to SelectedItem.

```
private void RebindData()
    {
        CollectionViewSource serversViewSource = (CollectionViewSource)(FindResource("serversViewSource"));
        var selectedItem = (Server)componentsDataGrid.SelectedItem;
        IQueryable<Server> serversQuery = this.GetServersQuery(_prodEntities);
        serversViewSource.Source = serversQuery.ToList();

        foreach (var item in (IEnumerable<Server>)serversViewSource.Source )
        {
            if (selectedItem.PropName == item.PropName)//Compare the values here
            {
                componentsDataGrid.SelectedItem = item;
                break;
            }

        }
        //serversViewSource.View.Refresh();
    }
```

Comment: thanks, but i dont understand this line "But you will have to find the item in Collection that has same Values as that in preserved SelectedItem before you assign that object back to SelectedItem."

Comment: is it possible to achieve this from xaml?

Comment: It means that reference of your SelectedItem should be same as one in your collection.Can you pleas show the Type of your collection.

Comment: No I dnt think its possible in xaml.

Comment: I don have any collection, I jus dragged and dropped the datagrid from the data sources and modified the auto generated code. is there any other way to do the same using collection ( means from entity) . I can try.

Comment: See all what you need is to compare values. The one that will have same values set it as SelectedItem. Like Suppose a Student with name abc and rollno 1 is SelectedItem of your DataGrid . Now you preserve this in a variable before you make DB hit. Now after you get Data from DB you iterate on it and find the Student which has name equal to preserved variable name and rollno equal to preserved variable rollno and assign this Student to SelectedItem of DataGrid

Comment: That is what I am doing now. but the focus on the selected row is lost after the timer restarts, anyways thanks for your kind response so far

Comment: I get this error - "foreach statement cannot operate on variables of type 'object' because 'object' does not contain a public definition for 'GetEnumerator"

Comment: oh yes you need to cast it to IEnumerable<Server> I updated it

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/26255/discussion-between-buba1947-and-ethicallogics)